# how to make animation run smoothly in Java 8?

Tags: java, animation

Java-Code:

```
public class Grafik_Test extends JPanel {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(new Grafik_Test());
    f.setVisible(true);
}

int x = 0;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    x++;
    g.drawString("X ist: " + x, 20, 30);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    this.repaint();
}

}
```

Java-Version: jdk 1.8.0_65

Problem:
I am working on a Java program with timer. After a short time the program throttles to ~ 2fps - with mouse or keyboard input it animates more quickly. With Java 7, the program runs as desired, but i want to implement it in Java 8.

Sorry for my bad English.